# Recusive query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have model with parent/child relation, 1 category can have 1/more subcategory

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private int id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Set<Category> children;
```

When I use findAll() (spring-data-jpa), I have result like

```
[
{
   id:1
   children: [ 
        {
            id:2
            children: [] 
        },
        {
            id:3
            children: [ 
                 {
                     id:4
                     children: [] 
                 }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
  id:2
  children: []
},
{
  id:3
  children: [
       {
          id:4
          children: [] 
       }
  ]
},
{
  id:4
  children: [] 
},
{
  id:5
  children: [] 
}
]
```

I want a native query or something like (select ... distinct) which returns the root categories only and not categories which are only children of other categories. So 2, 3 and 4 shall not be part of the expected result (see below).

```
[
{
   id:1
   children: [ 
        {
            id:2
            children: [] 
        },
        {
            id:3
            children: [ 
                 {
                     id:4
                     children: [] 
                 }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
  id:5
  children: [] 
}
]
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your result is not at all understandable. Could you please elaborate more with realistic values so as to know what exactly is duplicate..

Comment: @TeJas, I just add edit

Answer (score 0):

You should try a HQL query like this one (just an example and untested, but hopefully it points you in the right direction to go ahead):

```
String hql = 
    "select c from Category c where c.id not in (" +
        "select distinct child.id from Category p join p.children child" +
    ")";
List<Category> rootCategories = 
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).list();
```

Comment: Tks, I'll search raw query